# attribute element is scaled weirdly

Tags: html, css, element

[image: Bugged Element]

```css
.otherprogramTemplate {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  width: 400px;
  height: 185px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
}

.otherprogramButton {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://github.com/Necrosis000/Necrosis-Random-Colour-Generator" class="otherprogramButton">
  <div class="otherprogramTemplate">
    <p class="programTitle">Other Programs</p>
    <p class="programDesc">Click here to go to a list of my other programs/websites</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

I'm really unsure why but my elements width is greater than the actuall size of the div and I don't know why the blue part should fit around the red part but it's longer and stretches around the whole screen.

The height is fine it's just the width

Comment: Define 'scaled weirdly' as we have no clue what it is supposed to look like...

Comment: It’s supposed to be the size of the div but it’s width is way longer than it should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:**
Adding `display: inline-block` to your `<a>` should fix it.

**Explanation:**
Why is it covering the whole width? Because `a` tag has a default display type of `inline`. This means that it will take up the width of it's content.
Now, the direct child of this `a` is a `div` which has a default display type of `block`. Since block elements have a tendency to cover up the WHOLE row, this is being spread across the screen width.
Adding width to a `div` without changing it's display type would have no effect.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works a little but It's caused my element to not be center is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Try adding `margin: auto` to it.